# How to dynamically add decorator to class in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Suppose I have a class like the following, I can attach a decorator to a class when I define it.

```
@MyDecorator
export default class MyClass extends BaseClass {}
```

However I have the use case, where I want to be able to decide at compile time, whether or not hte class needs the decorator or not. Something like this:

```
export default class MyClass extends BaseClass {}

if (process.env.DECORATE) {
  // obviously "pseudo" code.
  MyDecorator.call(MyClass)
}
```

Does Typescript offer a way to achieve this? A decorator is only a function, so I'm guessing there has to be a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case all I needed to do was call `MyDecorator` like a function with `MyClass` as argument, so `MyDecorator(MyClass)` worked for me.